# How to get package name without website?

Tags: android

I've recently started creating an app for Android using SDK.Could anyone please tell me how to get Package name without any Website.I don't won any website ? Any reply is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you even tried googleing about that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need a website to assign a package name. It is just a java standard. Package names can really be any [a-Z0-1] name you want, so long as it is unique to the dependencies you are using, even then, the only thing that needs to be unique is the class names.

Comment: And,by the way,could you give any example for package name pattern ?

Comment: @user3276049 As I stated, while the package name does not necessarily need to point to a website, it is still common practice to use the format. So that pattern would look something like `com.[company].[product]`

Comment: @user3276049 Yaya, don't forget to accept if you're satisfied with the answer.